# Obtaining Databases from SQL Server 2008 using vb in VS 2012

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am fairly new to asp.net but have knowledge is vb. I am building an web application in visual studio 2012 using vb. I have a drop down list that is populated with two 2008 SQL Servers. There is another dropdown that will need to populated with a list of available databases on the selected server. I have a button that once clicked and the server is selected it will do a query and pull the list of databases

I have specified the server name in a globalvariables class and then imported it into the form I am using.

I am thinking that will need to do a IF statement that will need to say, If server1 is selected the open a connection and perform a query on the databases.

Here is my code that I have but its throwing an overload resolution failed because no accesible 'Open' accepts this number of arguments error:

```
Protected Sub getdb_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles getdb.Click
        Dim objConnection As OleDbConnection
        objConnection = CreateObject("OleDbConnection")

        If DropDownList1.Text = globalvariables.servername1 Then
            objConnection.Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=" & "globalvariables.servername1" & ";" & _
                "Trusted_Connection=Yes; Initial Catalog=master")

        End If
```

Please help me in getting the correct code as I have tried a number of items off of this site and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You use the New keyword to instantiate your objects

```
Dim serverName = DropDownList1.Text 
Dim connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=" & serverName & ";" & _
                       "Trusted_Connection=Yes; Initial Catalog=master"
Dim objConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)
objConnection.Open()
```

and pass the instructions on how to open the database using a connectionString.
However, because you are using a SqlServer database why don't you use the specific classes provided for Sql Server?

[SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx), [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx), [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) and so on....

Comment: If I want to have it for the second server do a new connection string and then reference the text from the dropdown in a if statement?

Comment: Well, if the dropdown contains exactly the server name you could remove the need to use a global variable. (You should be sure that there is always a server names selected of course) Answer updated

Comment: Can I use the server explorer and connect to the two sql servers and then when the user selects the server from the drop down it decides which server to connect to and open the connection? If so what code would I use for this?